# Delete files older than excluding directory (Linux)

Tags: linux

I'm trying to remove all files and subdirectories from current location older than, let's say, 14 days EXCLUDING folder "Folder". What I try is
`find . -mtime +14 -not -path "./Folder/*" -delete` but despite the fact that without "-delete" flag it displays records excluding "Folder" subdirectory, with "-delete" flag it tries to delete "Folder" as well. How to exclude "Folder" from deletion? And how to ensure that too old subdirectories (excluding "Folder") will be deleted even if not empty? Or is there any better option to achieve this? It has to be executed from groovy script on external Jenkins server, so simple bash command is preferred way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```bash
find . -mindepth 1 -type d -not -name "Folder" -mtime +14 -exec rm -r {} + -o -type f -not -path './Folder/*' -mtime +14 -exec rm {} +
```

I tested it with a subfolder and file within that was set to older than 14 days along with the subfolder "Folder" also being older than 14 days. It deleted the correct subfolder and skipped folder, may work for you.

**Explanation**: Starting at your current depth in the file tree, it will first delete all folders considered older than 14 days, and their contents recursively. Then it will delete files considered older than 14 days. You may get missing file errors, this is due to those files already being deleted from the recursive statement. The `-o` allows this to both look at directories and files, joining the two statements together.